# google spreadsheet drawing while freezing rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets

After my sheet is frozen for maximum amount of rows (10)  and columns (5), I'm inserting a drawing as a button. I assigned a script to the button. The problem is:

I can't move that drawing into the frozen quadrants of the sheet. The drawing pushes up against the frozen border. I want that button at all times as I scroll through the worksheet. However, if the button is not in the frozen sections, but in the 4th quadrant, I have to scroll to it to push the button.

Does anybody know a way around this? How do i get that button to be always visible on a large worksheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a long-standing issue, unfortunately (and this behaviour remains in the new version of Sheets). If you are using the new version, you might want to look into [sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars).

Comment: Thanks Adam. I will try it. Interesting feature. Didn't know about sidebars. thx.